# Jquery - Selecionar e desselecionar elementos na página

Tags: javascript, jquery, aplicação-web

Tenho uma tela com varias divs que são arrastáveis.

Entretanto, preciso que quando o usuario clicar nelas, ela crie uma borda ao redor e adicionasse algumas opções (deletar, por exemplo).

Mas quero que quando ele clicar fora deste elemento, que saísse essa borda e sumisse também as opções.

Estou tentando da seguinte maneira, mas ele ao invés de pegar o que foi clicado, ele pega o document:

```
$(document).click(function() {

var objeto = $(this);

if( objeto.prop('class') == "adesivo" ||  objeto.prop('class') == "quadro")
{
    selecionaElemento(objeto);
}
else
{
    deselecionaElementos();
}});
```

A função `selecionaElemento(objeto)` faz o seguinte:

```
function selecionaElemento(objeto){
  objeto.css("border", "1px solid #F00");
}
```

E a deselecionaElementos() faz o seguinte:

```
function deselecionaElementos(){
   $('.adesivo').css("border", "none");
   $('.quadro').css("border", "none");
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado que ao invés de pegar o elemento ele pega o document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indica um evento jQuery para adicionar um classe ao elemento clicado, e remover de todos e adiciona uma ao $(this).

```js
$(document).on('click','.div',function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.div').removeClass('selected');
  $this.addClass('selected');
});

$('body').click(function() {
  $('.div').removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.div{
width:40px;
height:40px;
background-color:#ccc;
border:1px solid #000;
}
.selected{

background-color:#222;
border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div'>1</div>
<div class='div'>2</div>
<div class='div'>3</div>
<div class='div'>4</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom. Irei adicionar aqui no codigo. Mas e caso ele clicar fora e não for uma dív? só colocar uma função no document.ready pra deselecionar geral?

Comment: Tinha esquecido dessa segunda, acabei de colocar na resposta.

Comment: Ok. Vou colocar aqui e, funcionando, coloco como resposta. Obrigado.